# Android: how a method in a class talk to UI?

Tags: android, user-interface

there,
Here's my code stucture:

MainActivity:

```
public class PureDataActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView statusView, logView;
        .....
        Connection myconnection = new Connection();
        myconnection.download()//I implement this in an AsyncTask, which I didn't type here
}
```

Class Connection: (which is a another file)

```
Public class Connection{
        private void download();
        //This method download some data from server for few minutes.
}
```

The question is how can I update the textview in UI every few seconds, with some data rate information? Since from the Connection class I cannot access UI .

I know in AsyncTask I can use updateProgress to access the UI, but it's outside the download() method. How can I access UI when download() is running?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html). This will help you out. Also, the [bluetooth chat](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html) example they provide should give you an idea of what you should do.

You are basically going to create a handler that you will use to pass your information back to the ui activity. This will help handle all the messaging.

Answer (score 0):

In your overridden runInBackgroundThread method in your AsyncTask, call publishProgress. Your overridden onProgressUpdate will then be called (at a later point) on your main thread, meaning you can update the UI.

That is the basis, however with network connections, it's likely you have a couple of methods to setup a connection then 1 method call that blocks until all the data is downloaded, meaning you can't publish your progress updates regularly whilst the data is downloading.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple callback. Here is an exemple where the Activity class implements the callback, but you can have your own object if you prefer.

```
public interface ConnectionCallback {
    void doYourStuff();
}

public class PureDataActivity extends Activity implements ConnectionCallback {

    private TextView statusView, logView;
        .....
        Connection myconnection = new Connection(this); // <-- this is where you pass the callback
        myconnection.download()//I implement this in an AsyncTask, which I didn't type here
    }

    @Override
    public void doYourStuff() {
       // do what you need to do on your TextView
    }
}

Public class Connection{
    private final ConnectionCallback connectionCallback;

    public Connection(final ConnectionCallback connectionCallback) {
        this.connectionCallback = connectionCallback ;
    }

    private void download() {
        //This method download some data from server for few minutes.
        // when you want to update your UI:
        connectionCallback.doYourStuff();
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. You use Connection myconnection = new Connection(this); as a constructor. But what if my constructor is Connection(arg1, arg2, arg3). Under this circumstance, what should I do to pass the call back?

Comment: new Connection(this, arg1, arg2, arg3) ==> "this" is just like any other variable that you can pass, it simply references the current object in the scope. Of course, this extra-parameter needs to be declared in your Connection constructor